# Closing a slider with jQuery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have it now where when you click on a + sign, a slider drops down with information. I cannot figure out how to make it to where if the user clicks on the - sign, the slider goes back up. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1o6xjkq/)

Here is the javascript I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Set default open/close settings
        $('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers

        //On Click
        $('.acc_trigger').click(function () {
            if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) { //If immediate next container is closed...
                $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all .acc_trigger classes and slide up the immediate next container
                $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); //Add .acc_trigger class to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
            }
            return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        });

    });
</script>
```

And here is the html

```
 <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Overview</a></h2>
 <div class="acc_container">
    <div class="block"">
        <span id="Content_lblOverview">TEXT HERE
        </span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but jQuery `.click()`, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your slideUp/down with slideToggle

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/8nLvh1ez/

```
    //Set default open/close settings
    $('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers

    //On Click
    $('.acc_trigger').click(function () {
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) { //If immediate next container is closed...
            $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideToggle(); //Remove all .acc_trigger classes and slide up the immediate next container
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle(); //Add .acc_trigger class to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
        }
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q1o6xjkq/8/)** - Using [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) determines the active state and either shows it or hides it accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
    })
});
```

For default state as hidden, simply add a `.acc_container { display: none; }` to your stylesheet.

Comment: Worked great, the only issue I see now is when it expands the section, the image doesnt change from a + to a - ,but other than that, it works like a charm.

Comment: I updated the answer & demo link to include the active class, didnt realize you were using it for styling. I also came up with another option using css's `content` attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/q1o6xjkq/5

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$('.acc_trigger').on("click",function(event){     
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
})
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/q1o6xjkq/7/)

Comment: the use of `on` doesn't really make this different than my answer.